# How to change colors with react color

Tags: reactjs, color-picker

I am using react color and i want to change colors.primaryColor so that to change the colors of other components but i don't know how to set them in state object. Is this possible or i am doing something totally wrong..

```
this.state = {
    colors: {
        primaryColor: 'green',
        secondaryColor: 'purple'
    },
    hStyle: {
        color: this.state.colors.primaryColor
    },
    divStyle: {
        color: this.state.colors.primaryColor,
        backgroundImage: 'url('+img17+')'
    },
    background: '#444'
};

handleChangeComplete = (color) => {

    this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state, {
        background: color.hex,
        colors: {
            primaryColor: color.hex,
        }
    }));

    };

render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <SketchPicker color={this.state.background} onChangeComplete={ this.handleChangeComplete }/>
            <Div style={this.state.divStyle} />
            <H style={this.state.hStyle} />
            <H style={this.state.hStyle} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What component is this in? What components do you want the color to be in? How are the components related?

Comment: Components are simple functions that receive styles from props and set them inline. The problem is with this  declaration color: this.state.colors.primaryColor

Comment: whats not working for you? do you get an error?

Comment: This looks correct to me, are you still having problems @Stasa